# border zone of the infarcted heart

Tags: molecular-biology

I did myocardial infarction experiments on mice and I am a newbie in this area. I need to isolate RNA and protein from the remote and the border zone. Where should I cut the heart so i can separate the infarct zone, border, and the remote zone? Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: I'm no expert but does this help? http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1888481/